# Merging Rows and Combining Data

Tags: excel, vba

I need to do the following with VBA in Excel:

Sheet 1 – data I populate:

```
Column X            Column Y
1                           A
1                           B
1                           C
2                           A
3                           D
3                           E
```

Sheet 2 - data populated by VBA code:

```
Column X            Column Y
1   A|B|C
2   A
3   D|E
```

I have this so far:

```vb
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim xInitialData As Worksheet
    Dim xNormalized As Worksheet
    Dim Val As Variant
    
    Set xPopulatedData = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1")
    nInitRows = xPopulatedData.Cells(xPopulatedData.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set xNormalized = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 2")
    xNormalized.Cells.Clear
    xNormalized.Cells(1, 1) = "Column X"
    xNormalized.Cells(1, 2) = "Column Y"
```

That copies the column headers from one sheet to another.

Answer (score 3):

- If you are using Excel 2016 or a later version (including Excel 365)

In E1, input the following UNIQUE function to get unique ColX values.

```
=UNIQUE(A1:A7)
```

Apply FILTER & TEXTJOIN Function in F1: use the FILTER function to filter all rows corresponding to each unique ColX value. Drag-fill to get all ColY values corresponding to each unique ColX value.

```
=TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,FILTER($B$1:$B$7, $A$1:$A$7=K1))
```

---

- VBA code

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey As String
    Dim arrData
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set rngData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 1)
        If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
            objDic(sKey) = objDic(sKey) & "|" & arrData(i, 2)
        Else
            objDic(sKey) = arrData(i, 2)
        End If
    Next i
    Range("E:F").Clear
    Range("E1").Resize(objDic.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(objDic.keys)
    Range("F1").Resize(objDic.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(objDic.items)
    Set objDic = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]